# iphone : How to draw line on Label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to make my label as shown in the image

[image]

I know I can get this effect by putting image view on it.

but is there any other method to do ?

How can I put line on label ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
UILabel *blabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XX, 6, 271, 26)];
blabel.text = @"Hellooooooo";
blabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
blabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
blabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
blabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
[scrollDemo addSubview:blabel];

//underline code
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [@"Hellooooooo" sizeWithFont:blabel.font constrainedToSize:blabel.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UIView *viewUnderline=[[UIView alloc] init];
viewUnderline.frame=CGRectMake((blabel.frame.size.width - expectedLabelSize.width)/2,    expectedLabelSize.height + (blabel.frame.size.height - expectedLabelSize.height)/2,   expectedLabelSize.width, 1);
viewUnderline.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[scrollDemo addSubview:viewUnderline];
[viewUnderline release];
```

**The line above will appear below the text. You just need to change Y for UIView and it'll do wonders :)**

Answer (score 0):

Place a `UIImageView` with line image on your label so when you run application it will fit.

Answer (score 0):

put another label with "***_***" over it
transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

you can create UIView with line's height and width and give background color to it. Put UIView over your UILabel .

Answer (score 0):

For one of my projects I've created an **UILabel** subclass, which supports **multiline text**, **underline**, **strikeout**, underline/strikeout line **offset**, different text **alignment** and different **font sizes**.

Please see provided link for more info and usage example.

https://github.com/GuntisTreulands/UnderLineLabel